# How to create a new <div> block usin js to paste overflow content if previous block doest have free space to keep it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do somthing like this 
  for example i have

```
       <div class="A4">
           content more then A4 size...
           and the overflow part i want to transfer to dynamically 
           created new <div>
       </div>
       <div calss="A4">
          overflowed content here
       </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Using multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts)

Answer (score 0):

Look into `appendChild` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp). I'd add a condition in your code. If the content of the first `div` is above a certain length, append a new `div` and put the rest of the content there.

Comment: i will give you an example   wwwww and iiiii   can you see the difference?